# \thelstlisting undefined for nostarch

Tags: errors, listings, templates

I'm trying to get `nostarch` working and it won't even get out of the gate.  I'm just a lowly user so these kinds of errors leave me quite clueless.

The sample doc in the distribution [nssample.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nostarch/nssample.tex) gives me the same error as this simple example does:

```
\documentclass[nocfonts]{nostarch}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

And I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \thelstlisting undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.580 \renewcommand \thelstlisting
```

Clearly `nostarch` is pulling in `listings` (or is it `listing`?), or maybe more correctly, it needs it but it isn't pulling it in?  I'm using a fully updated TeXLive 2011 on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Version 1.4 of `listings.sty` includes the following code snippet:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifundefined{thechapter}{\let\lst@ifnumberbychapter\iffalse}{}
  \lst@ifnumberbychapter
      \newcounter{lstlisting}[chapter]
      \gdef\thelstlisting%
           {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@lstlisting}
  \else
      \newcounter{lstlisting}
      \gdef\thelstlisting{\@arabic\c@lstlisting}
  \fi}
```

Version 1.3 of `nostarch.cls` contains the following code snippet:

```
\renewcommand \thelstlisting
     {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter-\fi \@arabic\c@lstlisting}
```

In other words, `nostarch` tries to redefine a counter (`lstlisting`) in the preamble which will only be defined by `listings` at the begin of the document body. This results in the error message you observed.

Solution: Copy `nostarch.cls` to your working directory and rename the copy to, say, `mynostarch.cls`. In the renamed copy, replace the above code lines with

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand \thelstlisting
       {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter-\fi \@arabic\c@lstlisting}%
}
```

Then, replacing `nostarch` with `mynostarch` in your example (and actually typesetting something in the document body) should compile without errors.

EDIT: As Peter Grill pointed out in a (now deleted) comment, adding `\def\thelstlisting{}` *before* `\documentclass` will remove the error message in your original example. However, `nostarch`s attempted redefinition of `\thelstlisting` (replacing the dot with a dash) won't be applied. Here's an alternative solution that doesn't involve modifying a custom copy of `nostarch.sty`:

```
\def\thelstlisting{}

\documentclass[nocfonts]{nostarch}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand \thelstlisting
       {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter-\fi \@arabic\c@lstlisting}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
foo
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow... I'm glad I asked :)  Googling got me nowhere and this was way beyond my meager LaTeX-ness.  Thanks very much!