# LaTeX Error: Command \thelstlisting undefined

Tags: listings

I'm using book class, and trying to change numbering on listing using

> \renewcommand\thelstlisting{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

but im getting this message

> LaTeX Error: Command \thelstlisting undefined.

refering to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49447/thelstlisting-undefined-for-nostarch), i still can't figure it out

ps. i was changing \thechapter to Roman so i change \thelisting to arabic again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\thelstlisting` is not defined until at `\begin{document}`. You can find this information in [`texdoc listings-devel`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings-devel.pdf), the documented implementation of `listings` package, page 188.

The following code defers the redefinition of `\thelstlisting` at `\begin{document}`, hence works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\thelstlisting{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=text]
  content
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! may i know where do you find this information? i read the listings.pdf but olny get "prints the running number of the caption."

Comment: @MNaufalShidqi That information is now added to my answer.